# SpringBoot Custom Health Indicator not showing up

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

So I have some code where I created a new class implementing HealthIndicator

```
@Component
public class SimpleHealthIndicator implements HealthIndicator { 
@Override
public Health health() {
  return Health.down();
}}
```

So basically I want it to always return status:down however it seems like I'm not overriding the methods as it still is returning "UP". What am I missing? Thank you all so much.